# Если у автора заголовок дробится точками, необходима ли последняя?

Tags: пунктуация

> Бразилия. Парати. Вид из ресторана.

---

> Бразилия. Веранда. Вид из гамака.
>
> ---

Заголовки отцентрованы ("выключка по центру").

Comment: Насколько я знаю, неправильно в конце ставить точку. И вроде это относится и к такому случаю, когда есть точки между частями. Жду подтверждения этому (или "этого"?..).

Comment: Тём, я поубирала; а вдруг расстрою автора: ему кажется всё таким симметричным...

Comment: По-моему, симметричнее как раз без точки, перед началом же её нету.)) Меня расстраивали точки в моей электронной книжке после названия каждой главы (ещё не дочитал, но привык и перестал замечать).

Comment: Галина, если не попросишь специально, сами не скажете ни за что! :) Запутался: "этому" или "этого" в первом комментарии.

Comment: Так всё равно ж. И чему и чего. Запросто. ***ПОДТВЕРЖДЕНИЕ, -я; ср. 1. к Подтвердить - подтверждать. Сведения требуют подтверждения. П. улик, гипотезы. Служить подтверждением слов (ЧЕГО). Найти п. в практике. 2. То, что подтверждает, чем подтверждается что-л. Собрать подтверждения. Найти в летописях п. чему-л.***

Comment: Спасибо, Галина!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно современным нормам точка в конце заголовка не ставится. Вот пояснение от Грамота.ру

> В современной русской печати в конце заголовка употребление точки не принято. Это положение узаконено специальными пособиями и справочниками для корректоров и редакторов; сошлемся хотя бы на последний такой по времени: «Точку в рубрике (заголовке. – Б. Ш.), вынесенной в отдельную строку, опускают, за исключением изданий для начинающих читать детей (напр., в букваре), чтобы не мешать закреплению стереотипа: в конце предложения надо ставить точку...

В случае двух предложений "Справочник издателя и автора" Аркадия Мильчина говорит следующее:

> В заголовке из двух самостоятельных, синтаксически не связанных предложений между ними ставят точку, а в конце, по общему правилу, точку опускают.

Я понимаю это так, что общее правило "в конце заголовка точка не ставится" должно быть выполнено всегда, за исключением некоторых детских книг.

Comment: Вот оно, вот, что убедит автора: *В заголовке из двух самостоятельных, синтаксически не связанных предложений между ними ставят точку, а в конце, по общему правилу, точку опускают*!